# OleDB: Not Recognizing tabs

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, oledb

My problem is that my tab delimited file is not being recognized as such.

I am importing this data into a GridView, but the grid view is returning only 1 column

```
   using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
                            @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly +
                            ";Extended Properties=\"Text;FMT=TabDelimited;HDR=" + header + "\""))

                {
```

Comment: See if [this](http://loknathblog.wordpress.com/tag/fmttabdelimited/) helps you

Comment: Will do. I am planning on upload my project to a shared hosting environment, as such, I probably will nto have direct access to IIS. Will this solution still suffice?

Comment: The Schema.ini solution WORKS! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED(See comments). Using Schema.ini file fixes the issue of tabs not being recognized.